# converting character to strings in transmitter and receiver Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using transmitter and receiver but I want to change the data type from character to int

receiver code

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>//include radioHead ASK library 
#include <SPI.h> // include dependant SPI libray

 RH_ASK rf_driver; // create ASK object
int ledon = 13;
String userid;
String password;
 //RH_ASK ID1; // create ASK object
//RH_ASK pass1; // create ASK object

void setup() {

  rf_driver.init(); //initialize ASK object 


  Serial.begin(9600); //setup serial monitor to 9600

  //if(!rf_driver.init())
       //Serial.print("init failed");      
}

void loop() {

  // set buffer to size of expected message 
  uint8_t buf[9];  
  uint8_t buflen =sizeof(buf);

  //check if recevied packet is correct size
  if (rf_driver.recv(buf,&buflen))
  {
    int i;
    // message received with valid checksum 
    Serial.print("id: ");
    Serial.println((char*)buf);
      userid =(char*)buf;
        Serial.println(userid);

  }

delay(5000);

   uint8_t buf2[8];  
  uint8_t buflen2 = sizeof(buf2);

   if (rf_driver.recv(buf,&buflen))

  {

    int i;
    // message received with valid checksum 
    Serial.print("password: ");
    Serial.println((char*)buf);
      password = (char*)buf;
      Serial.println(password);

  }
  delay(5000);
```

transmitter code

```
//Include RadioHead Amplitidue shift keying library 
#include <RH_ASK.h>
// Include dependatnt ISP library 
#include <SPI.h>

//create Ampitude shift keying object 
RH_ASK rf_driver;


void setup() {
 // intialize ASK objct
rf_driver.init();

Serial.begin(9600);

  //if(!rf_driver.init())
      //Serial.print("init failed");

}

void loop() 
{

  const char *pass= "123456789";
rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)pass, strlen(pass));
rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
delay(5000);

const char *ID= "A00034732";

rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)ID, strlen(ID));
rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
delay(5000);
```

Comment: The title and the text in the answer do not ask the same. What do you want to do? char to num or char to string? And the code is very bad formatted. I also don't see a variable (content) of the transmitter that can be converted or is `password` always a number? So what do you mean exactly?

Comment: If ID is a HEX value then it is too long for an int.

Comment: What exactly do you want to convert to a number, and why do you think that converting it to a number is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly understand what you are trying to do. (It looks like) you have a decimal representation of a number, encoded as a string of characters. "12345" is not a number but a series of characters. <sub>(Technically each character is a number with a certain ASCII value, the digit "1" has ASCII value 49 for instance.)</sub>

To convert "12345" into the number 12345, the CPU needs to take each character, find its digit value, multiply it by the correct power of 10 and add it to all the others. There are a few built-in ways that do this for you. The easiest is the `atoi()` function, e.g.

```
int x = atoi("150");
```

In your case, try this:

```
int userid = atoi((char *) buf);

Serial.println(userid);
```

Comment: Note that an `int` on an Uno is only 16 bits, thus `atoi()` is only good for numbers within [−32,768, +32,767].